# What is the exceptional divisor of a divisorial contraction?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $\pi \colon X\to Y$ be a divisorial contraction between $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial terminal varieties. Let $E\subset X$ be the exceptional divisor and let $\pi(E)=D$ be its image. It is true that $\rho(E/D)=1$ ? Or at least over an open subset $U$ of $D$? More precisely: if $C$ and $D$ are two curves contracted by $\pi$ onto points of $U$, is it true that some multiples of $C$ and $D$ are numerically equivalent in $E$ ? (or course this holds if one asks for a numerical equivalence in $X$).

If $D$ has codimension $2$ in $Y$, it is true as $\pi$ is just the blow-up of $D$ on an open subset of $D$. If $\dim(X)=3$ and $D$ is a smooth point or a point with mild singularities, this is also true as $E$ is a weighted projective space (by a result of Kawakita). In "On extremal rays of the higher dimensional varieties" of Tetsuya Ando (Inventiones, 1985), it is said that if $X$ is smooth and $\dim(D)=\dim(X)-3$, the general fibres are either $\mathbb{P}^2$ or $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$; in the second case, are the two fibrations of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ numerically equivalent in $E$ ?

Comment: Isn't the blowup of an ordinary 3-fold nodal singularity a counterexample? The exceptional divisor is a quadric, i.e. isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @TomDucat: Your example is not $\mathbb Q$-factorial.

Comment: Of course I mean an algebraically irreducible singularity which is locally analytically isomorphic to the standard ordinary node $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=0$. To be precise, this is case (E3) of Theorem 1.32 on page 28 of Kollár & Mori.

Comment: @TomDucat thanks, that is a good example. I guess that one can also do a similar example with a curve $C$ in a fourfold, with a divisor birational to $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times C$. Do you have some specific example like this?

Comment: I guess the obvious 4-fold example would be to take a product of my example with a curve $C$, but I don't have anything more interesting than that off hand. And just a comment on why my example wasn't covered by Kawakita's result: he classifies 3-fold divisorial contractions to non-Gorenstein points.

Comment: Thanks. I would be very interested to see an example on rational fourfolds, but with $C$ being any curve.

Comment: @TomDucat: I still don't think your example is $\mathbb Q$-factorial: It is the cone over a smooth quadric surface $S$. The two Weil-divisors divisors corresponding to the two rulings do not have a Cartier multiple.

Comment: No, it is only locally analytically isomorphic to that. In other words, take something like $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2+t^3=0$.